# Reading/writing from named pipes under mono/Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, named-pipes

I would like to read/write from a named pipe/FIFo queue under Linux.
I have tried the standard classes StreamWriter and other classes from System.IO, but it fails because it is using seek.
Has anyone ever written/read from a named pipe using Mono?.
I am managing to read and write - but not the same time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to open separate readers and writers; for some reason, Mono treats FIFOs as if they are seekable (it's a bug), even though they aren't.