# call C# code quickly from a webapp(php or something else)

Tags: c#, php, apache, mono, ipc

I found myself in a problem. My main webapp is written in asp.net and i use mono+apache2 to host it. When hosting files when using mono the mime gets screwed up so i'll need to do this in php or another language. However theres some logic required to find the path of the file. Theres quiet a few escaping and filters that goes through.

Whats a fast way to call C# code from another language? the mono process will be running on the same box so i figure i may be able to send a message and have it send one back or respond to it rather then launching a exec and reading  the stdout (i heard launching a process is expensive which is why it isnt a good idea to generate html via an exe)

Anyways, the box is debian (lenny i think) with perl, python and php available.

Comment: Can you define "fast"? You can leverage decently fast communication between two processes using something like a named pipe.

Comment: @vcsjones: I forget how name pipe works (i can figure it out fast in .net though). also i dont know how to do it in python/perl/php etc. If you can give me a quick example then great. -edit- actually apparently its difficult to use named pipes so maybe a socket is better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713660/reading-writing-from-named-pipes-under-mono-linux

Comment: Why don't you fix the mime issue instead of mixing in things with PHP?

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: I did fix it via asp but there issues with seek and all that. Which i forgot to mention. Mono breaks apaches response and many filters does not seem to be applied when running on mono

Answer (score 0):

Two options, there may be more.

1. Starting a process is expensive on Windows. On linux, this cost is extremely mitigated and it is a viable option here. This is btw. what's meant with the "pipe" comment. You "pipe" the output from the exe into your PHP page;
2. Use HTTP. If you just use PHP to "fix" problems, you can still retrieve the content via HTTP from the apache server internally and then convert it using PHP. The PHP site will then just become some kind of proxy.

Comment: It took me a bit to figure out what you mean by #2. I'm unsure how i would proxy the request to mono but the problem is the code to find the file on the filesystem. I still wouldnt know how to get it from the php end. But #1 sounds ok if its true linux does that

Comment: Concerning #2: can't you just request the web page from the apache server from the PHP page? Or do you have problems figuring out what the path of the web page should be?

Comment: figuring out the path is the problem. It probably wouldnt be hard to rewrite the logic in php but i'll have to look up a lot. Also the problem is supporting seeks in files (ogg). How would i do that in php?

Comment: That is very difficult. Random access into files is something that is hard and best left to the web server. I know it's probably possible to implement this in PHP, but I honestly would not know where to begin.